# Changes I make to CSS file don't reflect in browser for Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, templates

This is my first time creating a WP template. I used this tutorial: http://themeshaper.com/2012/10/22/the-themeshaper-wordpress-theme-tutorial-2nd-edition/

I am editing the style.css file that is in the template folder (WCCB Theme - Copy). It is on XAMPP, a local server, so there is no FTPing anything. I edit the file, and refresh my browser and nothing happens. Currently I only have one style in there, making H2s red, and the rest is blank (except for the header comment). Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

1: When I view the source, the file is listed as a stylesheet that is applied.
2: When I go directly to the URL of the file the browser can find it.
3: When I use the developer tools to inspect my H2, it says only user agent styles are being applied.

Initially it appeared as a caching issue, but I have cleared my cache (Chrome). I have no idea what is wrong. How can I get my CSS to udpate?

Comment: Are you sure you've targeted the h2 element correctly? Should be like this: `h2 {color:red;}`

Comment: @Omega Yes, that is exactly how I have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how I fixed this. I deleted the template from the WP admin panel and added it again with a different name and some CSS changes already made. It worked. Now I can change my CSS file and refresh my browser and the changes appear. Not sure what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the template folder (usually under: `/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/<your theme>`) and edit the file: `header.php` (don't forget to back it up first!)

replace the line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ?>" media="screen" />
```

with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ?>?v=123" media="screen" />
```

and refresh the page. 
If it wasn't refreshed and you're using WP Super Cache - delete the cache.
Still didn't refresh? run from prompt `service httpd restart` (it restarts the Apache) and try again.
Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I know I had problems like that before. Try ctrl+f5 to do full reload.

Comment: Yeah, tried that one too. Didn't do anything. I got it working somehow though.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is open the page on the Incognito Mode(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>) - if you are using Mac (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>).